# Option to open code-blocks in fullscreen

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

As the title says, can SO introduce a button/shortcut to be pressed on which the code block/s provided inside question/answer could stretch out fullscreen and can be reverted back.

The need for this feature arises when OP or answerer posts a code that is large and scrollbar appears and it is somewhat distracting to read it fully when mouse goes out of scrollbar area and page scrolls down instead of that code section.

Comment: In which direction? Horizontally or vertically or both?

Comment: @Tichodroma Both. Anyways it dosen't matters bc it will be opening up full screen.

Comment: There is a greasemonkey script for this [stackoverflow-code-expando](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/111973)

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I support your idea that we should have this feature. Some post has a lot of lines and some line even long too. Example, error from log file of android studio. It difficult to focus and sometime don't want to help to answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly support this request.

I really hate having to scroll so much when reading code. Over the past year I have been using StackOverflow I have been copy/pasting large code snippets into notepad just so I can read them properly. I've become so engrained in this habit that it wasn't until now I just realised how much time I've been wasting.

And to top it off, I can't even do CTRL+A on the code block to copy / paste into notepad easily :)

I hope this question gets revived after the 5 years it has been here and gets implemented. Clicki

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a feature is necessary. If a post contains code that is not readable in the normal mode of display, the post probably has a problem. The code should be shorted and/or formatted so that it fits in the normal space available.

And I don't think such a feature is what SO wants as a community for good code. A full-screen option would encourage people to drop even more unreadable code into their posts than they already do today.

Comment: I'm not at all supporting dumping of whole codebase in an answer , but different persons follow different code styles and everyone dosen't limits their code at 80 characters.Moreover as I have mentioned in my question , getting into fullscreen helps in focusing towards problem and avoids ux issues like double scroll jump.

Comment: A lot of posts have code that is formatted in this way. It's better to have an expand button than it is foster an attitude of down-voting people for not formatting their question. Besides, which screen size should people format for? We read this site on anything from ultra-wide monitors down to mobile phones.